# Flask-login @login_required Decorator does not redirect for certain Plotly Dash pages

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I have been attempting to implement a 'logout after inactivity' feature for our product based on Flask & Plotly Dash. I have used Flask's 'permanent_session_lifetime' to achieve this with the following code:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
    session.modified = True
```

I have also made sure that all of the Plotly Dash pages are using flask-login's @login_required decorator:

```
for vf in app.view_functions:
    if vf.startswith(url_base_pathname):
        app.view_functions[vf] = login_required(app.view_functions[vf])
```

This works perfectly for certain Plotly Dash pages, ending the flask session and redirecting the user to our sign-in page, but for any which implement the _dash-update-component request, nothing happens. Looking at the network tab in Chrome, I can see that the _dash-update-component POST request is made and, as desired, a GET request is then made to the sign-in page. I can also see that the html template for the sign-in page is being returned.

"←[32mPOST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1←[0m" 302 -

"←[32mGET /signin HTTP/1.1←[0m" 302 -

However, this template is then not being displayed.

Has anyone come across this issue before?